# My items disappear when I add another item with an SVG - Android Studio XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-drawable

First of all, I’m not necessarily comfortable with programming in Java, nor on Android Studio (I just started to develop on this language and this tool again after 2 years and a few stops).

In order to design a button, I created a drawable with a red circle of `69dp` in a `layer-list`.

Then I had to add a triangle in this round (in order to make a play button). Except that I couldn’t get the triangle I wanted, so I decided to import my triangle into SVG (it was simpler), and add it to my Drawable via another item with the `android:drawable="@drawable/triangle"` property.

Except that when this new drawable is imported, the round disappears completely, and only the triangle remains visible in my view.

Therefore, I added the following properties to my item that contains the triangle:

```xml
android:left="120dp"
android:right="-128dp"
android:top="128dp"
android:bottom="-128dp
```

I confess that I do not understand what is happening to me at the moment. Some explanations would not be refused.

Code :
triangle.xml :

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="29px"
    android:height="29px"
    android:viewportWidth="69"
    android:viewportHeight="69">
  <path
      android:pathData="M30.743,11.826C32.929,12.938 32.929,16.062 30.743,17.174L8.86,28.304C6.864,29.319 4.5,27.869 4.5,25.63L4.5,3.37C4.5,1.131 6.864,-0.319 8.86,0.696L30.743,11.826Z"
      android:fillColor="#F30000"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M30.289,16.283L8.407,27.413C7.076,28.089 5.5,27.123 5.5,25.63L5.5,3.37C5.5,1.877 7.076,0.911 8.407,1.587L30.289,12.717C31.747,13.459 31.747,15.541 30.289,16.283Z"
      android:strokeWidth="2"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:strokeColor="#ffffff"/>
</vector>
```

button.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/red_max" />
            <stroke
                android:width="69dp"
                android:color="@color/red_max" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="120dp"
        android:right="-128dp"
        android:top="128dp"
        android:bottom="-128dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/triangle">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And I import my drawable in my activity like that :

```xml
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/start_button" />
```

(You can test with and without android:left ; android:right ; android:top ; and android:bottom to see the problem)

Problem with image :

[image: Center correctly but don't show]

[image: The circle disappears]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first draw your triangle in center of its viewport , then :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#DD1010" />
            <size android:height="33dp"
                android:width="33dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item

        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/triangle">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and your triangle that I just change its viewport size. you must draw it in center of its viewport;

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="33dp"
    android:height="33dp"
    android:viewportWidth="33"
    android:viewportHeight="33">
    <path
        android:pathData="M30.743,11.826C32.929,12.938 32.929,16.062 30.743,17.174L8.86,28.304C6.864,29.319 4.5,27.869 4.5,25.63L4.5,3.37C4.5,1.131 6.864,-0.319 8.86,0.696L30.743,11.826Z"
        android:fillColor="#F30000"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M30.289,16.283L8.407,27.413C7.076,28.089 5.5,27.123 5.5,25.63L5.5,3.37C5.5,1.877 7.076,0.911 8.407,1.587L30.289,12.717C31.747,13.459 31.747,15.541 30.289,16.283Z"
        android:strokeWidth="2"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give specific width and height. And then, give it gravity.